Parameter control problem derived via Dirichlet principle / variational formulation of Poisson equation / Lagrange multipliers
The below is a distilled-down version of a more involved problem I am looking at. Suppose for simplicity that $\Omega = B_R(0) \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ and $R$ is very large. Let us further define $f_s\,\colon\, \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ given by $f_s(x) = \mathbb{1}_{B_1(s)}(x)$ with $s \in \Omega$ and $|s| < \frac{R}{2}$. In other words, an indicator function of a ball of radius 1 around some $s$ well inside the domain -- I am also happy to instead consider a radially mollified version of $f_s$ to ensure smoothness.
Let us further define $X = H_0^1(\Omega;\mathbb{R})$ and an energy $F_s\,\colon X \to \mathbb{R}$ given by
$$
F_s(u) = \int_{\Omega} \left(\frac12 |\nabla u(x)|^2dx - f_s(x)u(x)\right)dx.
$$
Such an $F_s$ has a unique minimiser $\bar u_s \in X$ which satisfies the (weak form of) Poisson equation with homogeneous Dirichlet boundary condition
$$
\begin{align*}
-\Delta \bar u_s &= f_s\;\quad&&\text{ in } \Omega\\
\bar u_s &= 0\;\quad&&\text{ on }\partial\Omega.
\end{align*}
$$
Minimising $F_s$ over $X$ is, in a nutshell, the standard variational or energy approach to solving such a PDE. Taking it one step further, we can also define
$$
I(s) := \min_{u \in X}F_s(u) = F_s(\bar u_s),
$$
and note that in this case
$$
I(s) = F_s(\bar u_s) - \langle \delta F_s(\bar u_s), \bar u_s \rangle = -\frac12 \|\nabla \bar u_s\|_{L^2(\Omega)}^2.
$$
I would now like to connect this with the theory of Lagrange multipliers on Banach spaces. See also relevant lecture notes on calculus of variations here. One way to do it is to start with a functional $F\,\colon X \to \mathbb{R}$ given by
$$
F(u) = \int_{\Omega} \frac12|\nabla u(x)|^2dx
$$
and look at the constrained minimisation problem
$$
J(s) := \min_{u \in X_s}F(u)
$$
where
$$
X_s := \left\{u \in X \,\mid\, {\rm ``}-\Delta u = f_s\;{\rm on }\;\Omega\;{\rm ''} \right\}.
$$
More rigorously, I think we have to define $G_s\,\colon\, X \to X^*$ given by
$$
\langle G_s(u),v\rangle = \int_{\Omega} \left(\nabla u(x) \cdot \nabla v(x) - f_s(x)v(x)\right)dx
$$
and define $X_s$ as
$$
X_s := \left\{u \in X \,\mid\, G_s(u) = 0\right\}.
$$
This is somewhat silly, of course, because in fact $G_s = \delta F_s$, essentially establishing that $\bar u_s$ is the only admissible function. As in the Wiki article linked above, there exists a Lagrange multiplier $\lambda\,\colon\,X' \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $\delta F(\tilde u_s) = \lambda\,\circ\,   \delta G_s(\tilde u_s)$, which in this trivial case leads to
$$
\int_{\Omega} (\nabla \bar u_s(x) - \nabla \lambda(x)) \cdot \nabla v(x) = 0, \quad \forall v \in X.
$$
Ultimately, we observe that
$$
J(s) = F(\bar u_s) - - \langle \delta F_s(\bar u_s), \bar u_s \rangle = -\frac12 \|\nabla \bar u_s\|_{L^2(\Omega)}^2 + \int_{\Omega} f_s(x) \bar u_s(x) dx.
$$
I am curious about the distinction between $I(s)$ and $J(s)$, when we try to think of them as a "control problem" for $s$, e.g. say we try to optimise where to place a "sensor" $s$. Is there some "canonical" way to say that e.g. $J$ is "better"? It certainly seems to retain more information about the underlying problem, because $f_s$ appears explicitly. Or maybe I am fundamentally confused and in fact we simply have $I = J$? Or maybe the way I define $J$ is wrong and there is other way to go about it? Thank you for any input you might have!

The second form is more typically used in control problems, but written in the following way:
$$
\min_{u\in X}~\frac{1}{2}\int_\Omega|\nabla u|^2~dx \\
\text{s.t.}~-\Delta u = f_s, \ x\in\Omega,
$$
where $X$ is some appropriate function space. You can restrict it further via, e.g., pointwise inequality constraints, but for this exposition this suffices. We now proceed via the formal Lagrange method to construct the augemented functional
$$
L(u,\lambda;s) = F(u) - \langle\lambda,G(u;s)\rangle,
$$
where $F$ and $G$ are defined as in your post. However, notice that we never explictly invert the constraint equation to specify $u_s$. That is, we do not use the mapping $s\mapsto u_s$ because differentiating and manipulating such a map is difficult. Instead we can write the stationarity conditions of the augmented functional to find the following necessary optimality conditions:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\text{State equation:}&~\delta_\lambda L = -\Delta u - f_s = 0 \\
\text{Adjoint equation:}&~\delta_u L = -\Delta \lambda + \Delta u = 0 \\
\text{Gradient:}&~\delta_s L = \left\langle\lambda,\frac{\partial f_s}{\partial s} \right\rangle = 0.
\end{aligned}
$$
I am omitting boundary conditions from these equations, but they will naturally come up when computing the variational derivatives. This formulation allows us to write out optimality conditions and compute the gradients of the constrained objective function without ever having to form the map $s\mapsto u_s$. Well-posedness of this map is still necessary, but we never need to actually form it and instead just solve the resulting PDEs. I'll just note that this problem is a bit atypical because the gradient of the objective $F$ has the same differential operator as the PDE constraint $G$ so some of the equations look odd, but this procedure works for more general problems as well.
If you would like a more rigorous treatment of such problems, check out Optimal Control of Partial Differential Equations by Troltzsch.
Tröltzsch, Fredi, Optimal control of partial differential equations. Theory, procedures, and applications., Wiesbaden: Vieweg (ISBN 3-528-03224-3). x, 297 p. (2005). ZBL1142.49001.
